# Get Querystring using history.back click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser-history

I have small requirement that I am passing query string from demo1.html to demo2.html.
in demo2.html, there is back button(history.back()) so when user click back button it will redirect to demo1.html. in this demo1.html, I want to get querystring value or previous page url using javascript or jquery.

please find the demo html script below for your reference.

**I need the query string value of demo2 page in demo1**

**demo1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
function display()
{
    var wind =  document.referrer;
    var preUrl = window.location.protocol;
    alert(wind);alert(preUrl);
}
</script>
<body>
Search Content of the document......
<a href="demo2.html?email=shiva@gmail.com">Search</a>
<a href="#" onclick="display()">Display</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**demo2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
function goBack() { 
    window.history.back();
    return false;
}
</script>
<body>
demo 2 Content of the document......
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()">Back</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Reards
siva

Comment: The requirement is not clear enough. You need the query string value of demo2 page in demo1 ?

Comment: yes i need the querystring value in demo1.

Answer (score 1):

Save the query string in the href that acts as the back button, then use location.replace()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
demo 2 Content of the document......
<a href="demo1.html?querystring-on-demo2-appended-here" onclick="location.replace(this.href); return false">Back</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

a) Use the solution offered ny user3036342. This won't make the actual browser Back button work as you want though.

b) Leave the query string alone and use cookies instead. Set the cookie in demo2 and make sure demo1 reloads (I found [this](https://coderwall.com/p/ndecha) but there might be a better way)

c) If the pages are on the same domain, you could use History API and AJAX to switch between demo1 and demo2. Then you have full control about what happens when user presses Back/Forward, but it will require some [reading](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) to understand.